# Error when debugging a data factory pipeline with global parameters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I added a few global parameters to a data factory pipeline. However, when starting a debug session, I get the following error. Any idea?

{"code":"BadRequest","message":null,"target":"pipeline//runid/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","details":null,"error":null}

Removing the global parameters fixes the issue.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as some screenshot about how to use these parameters in your pipeline?

Comment: Same issue here! Looks like a product bug: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/302845/getting-error-3434code3434badrequest3434message34n.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going into monitor in data factory and check the issue under error section?
I faced similar issue once when i debugged the pipeline...but resolved the error by getting info from monitor error and making necessary changes to pipeline.

Comment: Please use comment section for questions.

Comment: @AbdurrahimAhmadov, he actually provided more info saying they could see more about the error looking into the monitor. Which is what I did today and could fix the issue.